# HashMap and JSON lookup errors (Null reference)

Tags: java, json, nullpointerexception, hashmap

I am having a problem with a bit of code which does a json looking and is returning a 'null error' which I don't know why. I can see the values via a log, so I know that the information is in there. When the HashMap is being created, it is bombing out.

Can someone please let me know where I am going wrong?

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
private List<String> subList = new ArrayList<String>();
private List<String> subTitle = new ArrayList<String>();



for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
    String x = obj.getString("category");
    String y = obj.getString("title");

    subList.add(x);
    subTitle.add(y);

    listDataChild.put(subList.get(i), subTitle);      

    /* Log.e("subList", subList.get(i).toString());
    Log.e("subTitle", subTitle.get(i).toString());*/

}

Log.e("subTitle", subTitle.toString());
```

From what I can see, it is being passed the correct values, but it just isn't working. I keep getting:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.HashMap.containsKey(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Thanks!

Comment: listDataChild is not initialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize your HashMap:

`HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>`

Comment: @begeegs It happened to all of us. You are welcome. Please mark the question answered:) thx.